# How to read a word/string from a text file in python?

Tags: python

Means I wanted to read all the line which contains the same word or a sentence and then print them in python 3

Please help me with a easy way to do so.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using the basic functions of Python and a `for` loop.

Here is an example using random sentences for example:

"Hello world good bye world.
I am happy to see you.
Hola world how are you."

Let's say the sentences are contained in a file as file.txt. Using `open()` you can read your .txt file. Then just iterate over each string and print the line containing the word you need:

```
with open("file.txt") as f: 
    for i in f:
        for j in i.split():
            if j == "world":
                print(i)
```

Output:

```
Hello world good bye world.
Hola world how are you.
```